# Cloud Foundry SSH acces pivotal.io

Tags: ssh, cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to access an application in [pivotal](https://console.run.pivotal.io) with ssh with following command:

```
$ cf ssh my-app
```

I get the following error

> FAILED
>   Error opening SSH connection: dial tcp 52.70.248.13:2222: getsockopt: connection refused
>   I'm following the [documentation](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html) but still it fails.

Comment: Are you on a corporate network or network where the connection might be blocked?  It seems like the cli is unable to make a connection.  You could also try `ssh 52.70.248.13 -p 2222` as a test.  You won't be able to login with that command, but it should at least be able to establish a connection.  For what it's worth, I'm able to connect using that command.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of setting up the foundation, the platform operator can choose to allow `cf ssh` access or deny it completely. Check with your platform admin. It should be on the ER/PAS tile configuration.

If it is allowed, you will be able to `cf ssh` into an app instance's container.